# Flutter StreamBuilder after non null migration

Tags: flutter, object, dart, google-cloud-firestore, migration

I'm having a heck of a time trying to migrate, and I'm stuck at the StreamBuilder. The error is `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.` Here is my code that worked prior to the migration:

```
          StreamBuilder(
              stream: userCollection
                  .doc(_uid)
                  .collection('lists')
                  .doc(itemID)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.none:
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    break;
                  default:
                  // Completed with error
                    if (snapshot.hasError)
                      return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                    // Completed with data
                    var itemDocument = snapshot.data!;
                    if(snapshot.data == null)
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();

                    itemCategory = itemDocument!['category'] ?? ''; // <- ERROR HERE
                    itemTitleController.text = itemDocument!['title'] ?? '';  // <- ERROR HERE
                    _itemImportant = itemDocument!['important'] ?? false;  // <- ERROR HERE
```

Comment: Have you print/log what itemDocument is actually returning instead of assuming 100% is a Map?

Comment: I can't print anything out yet because I have a million errors that won't let me run my build.

Comment: Then you should fix that first. How do you know that is actually giving you an error if the code doesn't build? If the code builds and you actually are getting an error, then you should be able to print that value. If not, check what the IDE is telling you.

Comment: I haven't needed to update the app in a year and a half, and now I've come across all of these changes. Updated the IDE, flutter, dart, all packages, etc., now I have to make everything non null. I'm going through and fixing everything one by one, and until then I keep getting BUILD FAILED with Exceptions... I guess I will return to this later. Thought there might be something that I missed that was easily spotted. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: While doing the null safety migration is better to comment down the lines who're giving you error and fix everything else. Once you're sure the code compiles, you can go back to those error and make sure nothing else is breaking. The actual error could be anything as flutter will break mid compiling because is unsure from so many different problems.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var itemDocument = snapshot.data!;
```

With

```
DocumentSnapshot itemDocument = snapshot.data!;
```

then

```
itemDocument.get('category')
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? You're not giving extra context on why that should work as the problem is bigger than just calling a method. Plus, he's using "var", therefore, dynamic will be assume and ".get" will not be a valid method to be called (having an exception if is the case)

Comment: in parameter 'stream' of StreamBuilder he has assigned firebase firestore snapshot.

Comment: His StreamBuilder is not making use of any generics <Class>. And, again... his issues is bigger than that line, he's in the middle of a null safety migration and your "answer" is not adding any background on how that should fix it.

Comment: I think he was using old version of firebase_firestore plugin, snapshot.data not returns a Map

Comment: again, you're assuming.